# Error búsqueda en mongodb y javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Tengo este código

```
app.get(BASE_API_PATH_GB + "?percentage-over-total=:x1&percentage-over-total=:x2", (req, res) => {
    var x1 = parseFloat(req.query.x1);
    var x2 = parseFloat(req.query.x2);
    console.log(Date() + " - GET /general-budgets/percentage-over-total=" + x1 + "-"+x2);
    db.find({"percentage-over-total":{$gte:x1 , $lte:x2}}).toArray((err, budget) => { //mayor que x1 y menor que x2
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error accesing DB");
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        if (budget.length == 0) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
            return;
        }
        res.send(budget.map((c)=>{
           delete c._id;
           return c;
        }));
    });
});
```

En el cual quiero que en base a los porcentajes totales que tengo , que se pueda buscar un rango de mayor y menor porcentajes , pero al realizar la búsqueda entre 12.5 y 32 obtengo esta salida la cual es no la que quiero , y no sé que puede estar mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo deberían salir los 3 resaltados en amarillo. He instalado el módulo express,querystring..
La url que he utilizo : ../api/v1/general-budgets?percentage-over-total=12.5&percentage-over-total=32.0

Answer (score 0):

Puede que sea un problema de la API que estás utilizando `BASE_API_PATH_GB` no puede filtrar lo que le pides.

Si no puedes modificar esa API, puedes hacer un filter para obtener solamente lo que te sirve, yo cambiaría:

```
res.send(budget.map((c)=>{
  delete c._id;
  return c;
}));
```

por

```
const result = budget.filter(item => 12.5 <= item.percentage-over-total <= 32.0)
res.send(result);
```

Si quieres quitar `_id` de la respuesta, puedes utilizar un `.reduce` en vez de un filter.

```
const result = budget.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const { _id, ...restOfObject } = item;

    if (12.5 <= restOfObject.percentage-over-total <= 32.0) {
        return [...acc, restOfObject];
    }

    return [...acc];
}, []);

res.send(result);
```